# WooCommerce adding custom text to order processing email table

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We sell digital products using Woocommerce and I am working on order processing email `customer-processing-order.php`

In the email, there is a table that lists Product name, quantity and price along with download links

[image]

I am trying to add text right below the download links where the red arrow is pointing and so far I am not having any luck trying to find the hook/filter for this area

I have tried the following filter but this does not display anything

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_email_order_items_table', 'add_order_email_instructions', 10, 2 );
```

I have tried the following hooks but they do not display the text at the right area

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta', 'add_order_email_instructions', 10, 2 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'add_order_email_instructions', 10, 2 );
```

Is there any hook/filter for the area where I am pointing the red area at all?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler solution for you.

**Approach:** In your theme. Override WooCommerce's Email tempalate customer-processing-order.php and customize it as you like. (A simple google search on how to override woocommerce templates will help you here.)

**Hint:** The changes which you need to do id for the file emails/plain/email-order-items.php. So override the same and make ur desired changes.

**Note:** Rather than using the actual theme create a child theme and follow the above process. So that when the orginal theme updates your code won't be overwritten. (Search on how to create a child theme. Its lot more easy to customize by this approach).

Comment: This is not really an answer, your are telling me how to custom create an email template whereas I am asking for the hook/filter name. I am already doing all these. I already googled to find the hook/filter I am looking for, checked several questions on this website too but could not find the hook/filter so I ended up posting a questions here

Comment: As the download files are in the loop and no hooks are available to add your custom text. This is the last resort. Your just need to override the woocommerce's emails/plain/email-order-items.php template file. Either add your own hook in the loop or customize in the overridding file itself.